# jQuery fadeToggle() error

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I created a login page, and then the main home page. i didnot want people to get redirected to the main page after login so i used

```
$("#login").click(function(){
    $.post("homepage.php",function(data){
        var title = data.slice(data.indexOf("<title"),data.indexOf("</title>"));
        $("html").html(data);
        window.history.pushState(data,title,"/homepage.php");
    });
});
```

and this works great but the bug is that in homepage.php i have

```
$("#something").click(function(){
    $("#something-else").fadeToggle();
});
```

and it doesn't work, it throws an exception

```
VM8714:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

But i checked, the click event fires, and i did the

```
 $("#something").click(function(){
    var display = document.getElementById("something-else").style.display;
    if(display == "none") {
        document.getElementById("something-else").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("something-else").style.display = "none";
    }
 });
```

and this worked. any ideas?

Comment: jQuery's not going to produce that error (whether the element exists or not). There must be something *else* going on. Example where the elements exist: http://jsbin.com/jodumucuye/1 And where they don't: http://jsbin.com/jodumucuye/2 And where only `something` does: http://jsbin.com/sosafuhapa/1

Comment: You ***have*** to provide minimalistic sample to replicate your issue in question itself

Comment: Anyway, why are you using `$("html").html(data);`? Sounds like a strange idea

Comment: well, i saw that way on stackoverflow.  that was the way to change the url without redirecting and change the page content without reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the scene based on the information that you have given, and it worked fine.
login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>login.php</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
        $.post("homepage.php",function(data){
            var title = data.slice(data.indexOf("<title"),data.indexOf("</title>"));
            $("html").html(data);
            window.history.pushState(data,title,"/homepage.php");
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
</body>
</html>
```

homepage.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>homepage.php</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#something").click(function(){
        $("#something-else").fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="something-else">something-else</p>
<button type="button" id="something">something</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The verdict is the root of the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: well, maybe the "something-else" is not loaded?